# Can Googlebot bypass validation for reCAPTCHA?

Tags: captcha, recaptcha, googlebot

Can Googlebot bypass validation on its own reCAPTCHA system so that I can put it on my website without preventing Google from indexing it?

Comment: How about you take a look at this... http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=182072

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2621533/allowing-google-to-bypass-captcha-verification-sensible-or-not

Comment: I have looked there -- no reference to captcha.

Comment: Verifying the bot is Googlebot might not be needed if Googlebot can bypass captcha validation.

Answer (score 4):

Googlebot cannot automatically bypass your captchas; you have to let it. Look at the resource below for information on how to verify that Googlebot is really Googlebot:

- [Google Webmaster Central: How to verify Googlebot](http://googlewebmastercentral.blogspot.com/2006/09/how-to-verify-googlebot.html)